# В данный класс добавьте конструктор с параметрами для инициализации всех полей класса

Tags: c#

```
class Abonent
{
   public int id{get; set;}
   public stringSurname{get; set;}
}
```

Мой вариант:

```
    class inform 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] lines)
        {
           Abonent Human = new Abonent();

            Human.id = 13;
            Human.Surname = "Ivanov";
            Human.Abonent();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Abonent : inform
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public void Abonent(int id, string Surname)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.Surname = Surname;
        }
    }
```

Comment: в чем вопрос? Что пробовал, что не вышло?

Comment: class inform 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] lines)
        {
           
            int id = 13;
            
            string Surname = "Ivanov";
        }

    }

    class Abonent : inform
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        

        public Abonent(int id, string Surname)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.Surname = Surname;
        }
      
    }

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопка "править"

Comment: Начните с того, что такое явный и неявный конструктор.
Как инициализуется объект?
Вы, в данном случае обратились к свойствам объекта напрямую, после его инициализации через new()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объект можно инициализировать отдельно по каждому полю:

```
var human = new Abonent();
human.Id = 13;
human.Surname = "Ivanov";
```

А можно через конструктор:

```
var human = new Abonent(13, "Ivanov");
```

Важные моменты. 1) Конструктор не имеет возвращаемого типа: `public Abonent(...) {...}`, 2) На строке `var human = new Abonent()` возникнет ошибка, т.к. у вас в классе определен конструктор с аргументами и конструктор по-умолчанию (без аргументов) был удален. Подробнее [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.35.php)